# Can I hide a partition in Nautilus for a specific user/group?

Tags: permissions, users, udev, udisks

I'm trying to hide a partition form a specific group of users in Ubuntu 12.04.

I have created a new rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disk.rules with

`KERNEL="sda3",ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"`

And this works for all users.

I tried `KERNEL="sda3",ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1",GROUP="adm",MODE:="0700` but the partition is still hidden. That changes the group and permissions on the device rather than the rule.

How do I make the rule only apply to a particular group of users?

Comment: As far as I understand udev, it does not care whether or not a certain user is logged in. I'm afraid there is no simple solution for your problem. Of course I might be wrong and hope someone else comes up with a bright idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I presumed that udev couldn't do it but maybe there is a way of loading the rules file based on the users group who logs into nautilus? I don't know, would this be a bash script job?

Comment: To be honest, I've no clue if that can be done, because the udevadm man page states: "Reloading rules does not apply any changes to already existing devices."

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to hide all files inside a specific folder remove the execute permissions on that folder for the user or group you want. That disallows them from entering the folder.

```
chmod g-x /path/to/folder
```

The `g` stands for 'group'. And '-x' means 'remove execute permissions'.